# GPy and GPyOpt import issues

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, bayesian, gpy

I am trying to use GPy and GPyOpt (BayesianOptimisation()).

Whether i use Jupyter/Anaconda or Google Colab, i am having major problems even importing it.

I have tried all advice i have found so far and it seems to be a probem gong back some time.

Just a simple code like this:

```
# --- Load GPyOpt
from GPyOpt.methods import BayesianOptimization
import numpy as np

# --- Define your problem
def f(x): return (6*x-2)**2*np.sin(12*x-4)
domain = [{'name': 'var_1', 'type': 'continuous', 'domain': (0,1)}]

# --- Solve your problem
myBopt = BayesianOptimization(f=f, domain=domain)
myBopt.run_optimization(max_iter=15)
myBopt.plot_acquisition()
```

gives up an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6bfb00d9a176> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # --- Load GPyOpt
----> 2 from GPyOpt.methods import BayesianOptimization
      3 import numpy as np
      4 
      5 # --- Define your problem

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'GPyOpt'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.
To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
```

I have tried to install and update GPy and Numpy (research indicates its a linked problem).

I have ensured i dont have multiple versions of each downloaded and so on but no luck.

Any help would be gretly appreciated.
Thnak you

Comment: Did you install `GPyOpt`?  You didn't mention that, and it is a separate package from `GPy`.  And remember you have to install it WITHIN the package you are using (Jupyter or Colab).

Comment: Please focus on one or the other. Jupyter and Google Colab aren't the same thing. Google Colab sadly is majorly customization of an old fork that doesn't include the magic install commands. You should try `%pip install GPyOpt` in a new cell inside a Jupyter `.ipynb` file and then let it complete. It takes a bit of time to run. Then after it completes, restart the kernel and run `from GPyOpt.methods import BayesianOptimization`. I just tried that exact sequence on a remote session served via MyBinder and it worked. I'll post a follow up where you can try it yourself for comparing.

Comment: To do that I said in a fresh system without touching your own further, you can get a temporary remote session by doing this: Go [here](https://notebooks.gesis.org/binder/) and put `https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements` in the top line of the form where it says 'GitHub repository name or URL' and then hit the orange launch button on the right. When the **temporary, remote Jupyter session** comes up you can run the steps I suggested in my comment above.

Comment: See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the magic install commands added a few years ago to insure the installation occurs in the proper environment where the kernel is running that underlies the active `.ipynb` file. Use of install commands in the notebook with the exclamation point doesn't insure the proper environment & can sometimes cause issues. See [the second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez)...

Comment: <conitnued>to get a better sense about how the exclamation point use with installs can lead to issues and confusion. (Note: At present this doesn't hold for Google Colab because what is currently used was branched off the Jupyter project before the magic install commands were added. So only use of the exclamation point with pip is possible there & it should work effectively. Your statements suggest vaguely that was not your experience, but lacked details on that & that is why I suggest you focus on one or the other in your post as they are more different that most folks appreciate.)

Comment: Shoot. I just realized you have a third (sort of) option in there, namely Anaconda. What I said above applies to Jupyter without Anacaonda/conda involved.  If you are using Anaconda & Jupyter together, always preferably use a conda recipe if it exists. And this you'd always use `%conda install` in the running `.ipynb` file. For example, if you wanted to install Pandas, you'd base the full command on [what is listed here when you search 'pandas conda forge'](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pandas) & would be `%conda install -c conda-forge pandas`. Fall back to `pip` only if no conda recipe.

Comment: <continued> There happens to be a conda recipe for GPyOpt, as can be seen [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gpyopt). So you should be using `%conda install -c conda-forge gpyopt` in your Jupyter running from the Anaconda navigator. **Then when it completes (it will much slower than `pip`, restart the kernel.** And then try the import statement in your running `.ipynb` file. When you use Anaconda/conda you've chosen that as your primary package manager and must stick to that for the most robust & portable environments. Only fall back to `pip` if there is no alternative.