# No module named 'torch' in Jupyter Notebook although pytorch is installed

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pytorch, virtualenv

The Jupyter Notebook not able to find the torch module,despite I have it installed.

[image: Jupyter Notebook]

In the console it has no issue to import torch:
[image: command prompt]

How do it fix the issue so that I can import torch in Jupyter Notebook?

Note: the kernel "scan_env"(Jupyter) is the exact virtual environment "scan_venv"(command prompt)

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's lots of answers already covering this. What did you try on those pages? I'd suggest from your screenshot, that probably most of the issue is you are having trouble discerning the outdated information from the current best practices. You should not be using an exclamation point with the install command for running inside a modern Jupyter notebook. Did you try `%pip install torch torchvision torchaudio`? See my comments at 18:17 and 18:18 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77114432/gpy-and-gpyopt-import-issues#comment135943911_77114432).

Comment: Also **be sure to restart the kernel after using the magic install pip command** (`%pip install`). The magic version of the install command that insures the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel is running that underlies the active `.ipynb` file. (The exclamation point sends things off to a shell instance that may or may not be the same environment where your Jupyter notebooks is running. That problem is a big part of why the magic install commands were added a few years ago.) **After the restart of the kernel, then you can try the import** statement.

Comment: Also, help those who you hope will help you. Always include code and errors as text. For example, here I had to type out your entire install command which I could have simply copied if you had provided it properly. See the last bulleted item under 'Help others reproduce the problem', specifically 'DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.' on the page [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Wayne I used `%pip install` and restarted the kernel, and it now can import torch :)

Comment: @Wayne thanks for your detailed suggestion. I will paste out the code instead of image in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For installing from inside an active Jupyter `.ipynb` file, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the magic install commands added a few years ago to insure the installation occurs in the proper environment where the kernel is running that underlies the active `.ipynb` file.

From the original post, I know you were using `pip` for that package, and so the magic install command for running inside the active `.ipynb` file would be:

```py
%pip install torch torchvision torchaudio
```